# Prototype.js Cannot call class as function

Tags: javascript, magento, prototypejs, shopify-javascript-buy-sdk

I'm having conflicts with the Shopify Javascript Buy SDK and prototype.js. I'm using Magento 1 to implement a custom cart (because using Magento's cart is not feasible for this particular project), however I'm getting this error.

[image]

Here is my SDK implementation:

```
      const client = ShopifyBuy.buildClient({
            domain: 'your-shop-name.myshopify.com',
            storefrontAccessToken: 'your-storefront-access-token'
        });
        client.checkout.create(lineItemsToAdd).then((checkout) => {
            window.open(checkout.webUrl, null, "fullscreen=no,toolbar=no,height=800,width=1100");
        });
```

How can I resolve or bypass this conflict?

- protoype v1.7
- shopify prototype v2.2.4

Comment: We can't help you with the fragmentary information in the question I'm afraid. It appears that some code, somewhere, is trying to call an ES2015+ `class` constructor function with a normal call. Perhaps you have a Prototype.js "class" trying to extend an ES2015+ class (it can't, the way it tries to call it will fail with this error). But we really can't tell from what's in the question.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for your help. I was able to resolve this issue by updating prototype.js to 1.7.3 from 1.7. This library is no longer supported it seems, thankfully it worked out.